# Are todays phone cameras capable of capturing better video than no-zoom pocket camcoders?

Tags: camcorder

I am a complete amateur with respect to photography. I capture videos rather than still pictures during my vacations. So it is limited to videos outdoors. My preferences are limited to compactness of camera and outdoor video quality. Since I mostly upload it to YouTube, I don't need ultra HD resolution videos, 1080p will be fine.

For my vacations, I was using Sony Cyber-shot DSC-TX100 which enabled me to capture good quality outdoor videos in 720p resolution [may be because of HDR video mode and large sensor size] and had the compactness I was looking for. After this got damaged one year back, I was using my "One-plus One" phone for capturing videos. It even offers a 4K video shooting resolution and I have seen a lot of praise for this phone's camera all over the internet. But for me it turns out to be a grave disappointment when I compare the video quality of my old cyber-shot with "OnePlus One". The video had lot of grain and the "life-like" thing was missing. So now I am looking for another camera/phone which offers me better video quality outdoors. I live in a country where there is abundant sun light on most days. So I have to shoot my videos in bright light.

I know the no-zoom pocket camcorders are disappearing from the market. But I think one of these could meet my requirements of ultra compactness and better video quality than phone cameras. I still haven't made up my mind about going for a new phone (which is a costly option) assuming the new phone will offer better video quality (than my OnePlus One) or getting one of the pocket camcorders like GE DV1 or Panasonic HMA-T1.

Could anybody out there who has used both a pocket camcorder and a good phone, suggest which will be my best bet? Either to upgrade my phone or to buy the pocket camcorder? Does the pocket camcorders usually has bigger/better sensors than the phones? Which one could offer me better video quality? As I mentioned earlier I am not looking for any resolution beyond 1080p.

My budget is limited to 200$ if it is a compact camera and 400$ if it is a phone. Thanks.

PS: I have no option to buy another Cyber-shot compact camera since it is no longer available in my country. Also I am NOT looking for any camera with zoom such as Cyber-shot RX-100 even though it will be more value for money.

Comment: They do say that the best camera you have is the one you have with you. Phones tick that box.

Comment: No zoom "pocket cameras"? I fail to see how that can be better than today's typical smartphones.

Comment: @fredsbend : I never used one. I was asking opinion about these _flip, playsport, GE DV_ series of products, whether they are better than typical phone camera. IMHO, the Cyber-shot video was better than the video from my phone.